# Friendly URL (Mod Rewrite) not working over Parked Domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up friendly URLs to work with parked domains also. I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.example.com/home/
RedirectMatch ^/[index.php|index.html|index.html]$ http://www.example.com/home/

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ^/home[/]*$
RewriteRule ^/home[/]*$ http://www.example.com/container.php?page=index [P]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} [a-z]*[|/](images|styles|javascripts|includes)(.*)
RewriteRule [a-z]*[|/](images|styles|javascripts|includes)(.*) http://www.example.com/$1/$2 [P]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !(images/|styles/|javascripts/|includes/) 
RewriteRule ([a-z]*)[/]$ http://www.example.com/container.php?page=$1 [P]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/home\/" [R=301,L]
```

The principle is that I would like any URL like `http://www.example.co.uk/win`, `http://www.example.com/win` to load the page `http://www.example.com/container.php?page=win` or `http://www.example.co.uk/games`, `http://www.example.com/games` to load the page `http://www.example.com/container.php?page=games`. I've also added rules to exclude images, javascript, styles and includes directories.

If the user goes to `http://www.example.co.uk/index(.php or .htm or .html)` then it will redirect to `http://www.example.com/home/`.

For some reason my code isn't working. I don't understand why not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your using both mod_alias and mod_rewrite. do you want to stick to one

Comment: Could you suggest an alternative? Not sure what the difference is. I find the Apache documentation very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

your using both mod_alias and mod_rewrite, i don't believe you will need to exclude your static content because your only routing 4 static entries. clean up the .htaccess file and give this a try.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.example.com/home/
RewriteRule ^index.(html|php|htm)$ http://www.example.com/home/ 
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !(images\/|styles\/|javascripts/|includes/) 
RewriteRule  ^([a-zA-Z]*)/$ http://www.example.com/container.php?page=$1 [P]
```

Comment: The page should be one of many different pages "win, games, jokes, videos, gallery..." is there a way to match everything but the images, javascripts, includes and styles directories? It also changes the URL in the address bar to http://www.example.com/container.php?page=win